# How this overlay color effect was created?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, color-theory

I'm struggling with a little problem. I want to recreate some kind of overlay effect, but I cannot get close to it. I hope some pros among you know how this overlay was created...

**Note**: I have tried all the blending modes of Photoshop but none of them could give me what I wanted. The closest blending mode seems to be the `multiply` but it actually removes the orange color from the tiles, which I don't want.

Here are the images, if you want to try to recreate the effect on your own:

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you are not able to replicate this effect with Photoshop or something else, do you maybe know, what kind of blending/filter or whatever could have been used to recreate this effect?

I have also tried with a temperature shift, since it looks like the blue is added to all the colors without destroying too much of the original color (we can still guess that the tiles were orange), but It doesn't seems to be the way to go either

Note: I've showed a simpler problem since the second picture contains only one color. I'd like to be able to use any kind of overlay image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get an absolutely *exact* match, but a Photofilter adjustment layer comes pretty close…

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is possible to replicate the PhotoFilter effect with Multiply and Luminance? I saw a post on the internet that say that PhotoFIlter could be replicated with Multiply and Luminance blending options. I've just tried but I can't. The idea is that I'd like to be able to use an image as an overlay where the image is not full flat (doesn't contain only one color like in my example)

Comment: Why didn't you ask the question you actually needed the answer to, rather than posting it as an addendum once someone had gone to the effort of answering the question you **did** post?

Comment: Don't worry. I'll accept your answer if nobody has a better idea. I thought It would have been easier for someone else to find the effect that was used if it is used on a simpler problem (flat image). Moreover I didn't thought this could have been approximated by a blending method that only takes 1 color as input. My bad

Comment: I'm not bothered about the points. I'm bothered about the fact that your question isn't what you actually wanted to learn - that only exists in comments.